# How to fix Turtle frames in the RViz?

Tags: ros, rviz, frame

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to learn RVIZ by doing the examples of a  book, but the tool is displaying an Error in its global status:

> Fixed Frame [map] doe not exist.

My Goal is to run the **roslaunch turtle_tf turtle_tf_demo.launch** demo, where turtle_bot can follow me using the key_inputs

[image: image description]

Any Idea how to fix this? and see my Turtle frames

please note that am following the chapter3 of the book  STEP by STEP, which by the way is not a rocket science recipe

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258324/how-to-fix-turtle-frames-in-the-rviz?/) by [ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ](https://answers.ros.org/users/29728/%CF%86xoc%C4%99-%EC%9B%83-%D0%BFepe%C3%BApa-%E3%83%84/) on ROS Answers with karma: 424 on 2017-03-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam26](https://answers.ros.org/users/29143/sam26/) on 2017-03-31**:
The instructions clearly mention that you are supposed to change the "Fixed frame" from map to world  while yours still point to map. And then add the TF tree from Add> TF: that is when your turtle frames are going to appear. Hope this clarifies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Assuming that you're following [this](http://www.ict.griffith.edu.au/%7Evlad/teaching/robotics.d/READINGS/Learning%20ROS%20for%20Robotics%20Programming%20%5BeBook%5D.pdf) book, the instructions are clearly mentioned in Chapter-3. Follow them carefully, and you'll find your way.

---

Originally posted by [sam26](https://answers.ros.org/users/29143/sam26/) with karma: 231 on 2017-03-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0